# current_date in redshift exclude today's date when i am using with between command

Tags: date, amazon-redshift

I want to query data for last 30 days including today from redshift table. below is my query.

my date_column's type is 'timestamp without timezone'

```
select * 
from mytable  
WHERE  date_column BETWEEN current_date - INTERVAL '30 day' AND current_date 
order by date_column desc;
```

It gives the result for 30 days. But it doesn't include today's result.

I want to query for 30 days result including today's result also.

Comment: Is date_column a DATE or a TIMESTAMP ? Please share the DDL and some data that should be in the results

Comment: date column is timestamp without time zone encode az64 and the  sample result is {
            "id": "1G1123456789012345",
            "activitytype": "VCUV",
            "requestedby": "username",
            "datetimestamp": "2023-01-05T11:40:29.000Z",
            "status": "Success"
        }

Comment: A DATE is comparable with a TIMESTAMP with the time 00:00:00. Everything after midnight won't match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a timestamp don't use `between` as it also compares the time part. Use a range query:

```
where date_column >= current_date - interval '30 day'
  and date_column < current_date + interval '1 day'
```

Note that the upper bound is using `<` together with "tomorrow"

With Postgres this could be simplified to

```
where date_column >= current_date - 30
  and date_column < current_date + 1
```

but Redshift isn't Postgres and I don't know if that would work there.